# Populate spinner from shared preferences

Tags: android, json, sharedpreferences, spinner

I have a JSON array stored in shared preferences. Here I get it in a string:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getContext().getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefs.getString("classes", classes);
```

Now I want to populate a spinner with the content from shared preferences. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use an array adapter and give it a list of items,where items is an ArrayList.In your case,you must populate the ArrayList with values from Shared Preferences.

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,items);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```